# Why the value of my variable keep changing in this function?

Tags: php, laravel, gd, intervention

In my understanding of the code below, the value of $image should be always the same (original value passed to the function), but surprisingly for me it keeps changing (the value of the first dd() is different from the second), resulting in worse quality images each time the resize() method is called. Shouldn't saving the resized value in a different variable(ex:$imageSmallJpg) keep $image immutable during the function execution?

```
private function saveTransformedImages($image, $imagePath, $storageDrive)
{

    dd($image);
    $imageName = pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);


    $imageSmallJpg = $this->resize($image, 500);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName . '-sm.jpg';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageSmallJpg);

    $imageSmallWebp = $this->convertToWebp($imageSmallJpg);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName  . 'sm-.webp';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageSmallWebp);

    dd($image);
    
    $imageMediumJpg = $this->resize($image, 960);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName . '-md.jpg';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageMediumJpg);

    $imageMediumWeb = $this->convertToWebp($imageSmallJpg);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName  . '-md.webp';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageMediumWeb);


    $imageLargeJpg = $this->resize($image, 1300);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName . '-lg.jpg';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageLargeJpg);

    $imageLargeWebp = $this->convertToWebp($imageSmallJpg);
    $imgSaveName = $imageName  . 'lg-.webp';
    Storage::disk($storageDrive)->put($imagePath . '/' . $imgSaveName, $imageLargeWebp);
}
```

related methods:

```
public function resize($image, $maxWidth)
{
    $img = Image::make($image);
    $img->resize($maxWidth, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $img = $img->save(null, 70, 'jpg');

    return $img;
}

public function convertToWebp($image)
{
    $webp = $image->save(null, 70, 'webp');
    return $webp;
}
```

Comment: and what is `$image` originally ... an Intervention Image object?

Comment: $image is originally a Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile

Comment: and what is changing about `$image`? what is the difference between the 2 `dd`s?

Comment: The second dd() seems to have the resized version of the first. First dd() has size: 5507849, and the second dd() has size: 13480

Comment: so in both `dd`s it says the type is an `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`? ... also why do you keep passing `$imageSmallJpg` to every call of `convertToWebp`?

Comment: just an error. I already even fixed it, but it is not related. But yes, the type is always Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, but with a different size.

Comment: also why are you calling `save` on the intervention image which saves to the filesystem and then saving it again with `put` on `Storage`? ... you are overwriting the file you are loading (the path to the uploaded file) so that is why you are seeing that as you are overwriting the uploaded file in temp

Comment: how could it save to the same path of the storage method if i pass a null value in the path argument? I use the save() method just to set the quality and format. In my undestanding i was saving it to the variable that will be returned.

Comment: `save` saves the file to disk ... an Intervention Image File is an object that holds file data (path and data) ... calling `save` with the `null` just means it will save to the current location (path and basename) ... `save` is for  'saving' (it just happens to call `encode`) .. if you want to encode call `encode` ..... https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php#L134  ... that is my guess what is happening since `Image::make` is going to keep loading the data every time fresh from its path

Comment: just tried it with $img->encode('jpg', 70) instead of save() and i get the same results. The problem is still the value of $image being changed somehow during function execution after the first resize.

Comment: make sure you are not calling `save` on the image object any where as you have 2 methods that are calling `save` on them ... the only saving that needs to be done is via the `Storage::put` calls

Comment: Actually you was correct. I am sorry. I had changed to encode only in the resize function. After changing it in the convertToWebp() function too, now the variable stopped changing. Thank you SOU MUCH. Submit a answer if you want and i will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `save` on the Intervention Image object that is created after the `Image::make` calls will save the data to the disk. So the uploaded file data on disk is being overwritten when you call `save(null, ...)` as it will just save to the current path. Then you are calling `Image::make` with that path so it is now loading that file again (which has new data - resized) instead of the original (which doesn't exist on the filesystem any more).

Just remove the `save` calls and if you want to encode the image you can call `encode` directly (since `save` calls `encode` before writing to disk any way). This should avoid the issue of the data being overwritten.

On a side note, you can actually do all of this resizing and encoding with one single Intervention Image object without having to keep reloading the data from disk by calling `Image::make` over and over again (you can have just 1 call to `Image::make`).